# concat each two nodes

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm having the following html code:

```
<dl>
  <dt>1</dt>
  <dd>2</dd>
  <dt>3</dt>
  <dd>4</dd>
  <dt>5</dt>
  <dd>6</dd>
  <dt>7</dt>
  <dd>8</dd>
</dl>
```

Now I want to concatenate each `dt` and `dd` tag, is that possible with xpath 1.0?
So the results should be:

```
12
34
56
78
```

Tried already something like this, but didn't work:

```
//*/dl[concat(dt/text(), ./following-sibling::node()/text())]
```

Comment: Not possible using XPath 1.0 as far as I can see...

Comment: Can you also use something in XPath's outer environment, such as XSLT or Javascript or Java? Otherwise, I think you are out of luck.

Comment: Too bad, but I got it working now. Had to work with python so... See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using python:

```
content = sel.xpath('//*/dl').extract()

p = re.compile(ur'<dt[^>]*>(.*?)<\/dd[^>]*>')

for s in p.findall(str(prod_specs)):

    print BeautifulSoup(s).text
```